# pcl_tracking in perception_pcl_electric_unstable gives nodelet error

Tags: ros, pcl, nodelet, tracking

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

I'm trying to implement tracking using pcl::tracking library. Everything builds normaly, but when I try to run nodelet I get an error:

```
     Failed to load nodelet [/Detection_Tracking] of type [Detector/Detection_Tracking]: 
Failed to load library /home/grega/ros_workspace/diploma/Detector/lib/libDetector.so. 
Make sure that you are calling the PLUGINLIB_REGISTER_CLASS macro in the library code, 
and that names are consistent between this macro and your XML. 
Error string: Cannot load library: /home/grega/ros_workspace/diploma/Detector/lib/libDetector.so: 
undefined symbol: _ZN3pcl8tracking21ParticleFilterTrackerINS_12PointXYZRGBAENS0_14ParticleXYZRPYEE11initComputeEv
[FATAL] [1342859395.359533594]: Service call failed!
```

Do I have to link somehow libpcl_tracking.so in CMakeList.txt? Shouldn't be that done automatically when I add pcl dependency in manifest.xml?

I'm using Ubuntu and ROS Electric.

Thank's for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39417/pcl_tracking-in-perception_pcl_electric_unstable-gives-nodelet-error/) by [Grega Pusnik](https://answers.ros.org/users/1849/grega-pusnik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 460 on 2012-07-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just found a solution. I added the following lines to CMakeList.txt

link_directories (/home/grega/ros_workspace/perception_pcl_electric_unstable/pcl/lib)
rosbuild_add_library(Detector src/preprocessing_tracking.cpp)
include_directories(/home/grega/ros_workspace/perception_pcl_electric_unstable/pcl/include)
target_link_libraries(Detector pcl_tracking)

Now it builds successfully.

---

Originally posted by [Grega Pusnik](https://answers.ros.org/users/1849/grega-pusnik/) with karma: 460 on 2012-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2014-04-27**:
I don't get one thing, the error string says it can't load "diploma/Detector/lib/libDetector.so"; but you linked pcl related library with the cpp file which contains the 'undefined symbol'.... I am facing similar kind of problem, posted a question http://answers.ros.org/question/157886/error-while-loading-nodelet-velocity_multiplexer/